# Create Table Header with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I want to create header of a table with the elements that are of the class "headerClass" but previously remove the duplicates with a JavaScript function. 
My JavaScript Function:

```
function getHeaderElements() {

var headerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("headerElement");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var uniqueHeaderElements = [];
$.each(headerElements, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueHeaderElements) === -1) uniqueHeaderElements.push(el);
});

output.innerHTML =  uniqueHeaderElements.toString() ;
```

}

However, I am not sure how I should iterate through the elements of the array and add them to the innerHTML, similar like in the code below:

```
output.innerHTML =  uniqueHeaderElements.toString() ;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you mix vanilla with jquery?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Vanilla makes jQuery taste better. ;)

Comment: instead of only `uniqueHeaderElements.push(el);`, you could do `output.appendChild(el);` too, this way you will only add the elements which are not already in your array to the dom and you don't need to interate again through your unique array.

Comment: Your array `uniqueHeaderElements` will contain just one element, is that right? If so, try it: `output.innerHTML =  uniqueHeaderElements[0].toString() ; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do the same loop as you have already done to add all your elements inside the innerHTML.

Try this out :

```
$.each(uniqueHeaderElements, function(i, el){
      output.innerHTML += el;
 });
```

Still, i'm not sur of what's inside your table uniqueHeaderElements. You may need to adapt this piece of code a bit.